# Use a map in Cloudformation to define static dev and prod configs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to have a single template for all my deployments.

I want my dev and prod configuration defined in the same template.

When I call the template I pass a param for dev or prod and cloudformation uses the variables for the dev or prod map- is this possible?

I can see its supports maps but Im unsure of how to achieve what i want with it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html

Is there a way I could make all my params maps and then have one param for dev or prod and when I set that one param when deploying cloudformation uses the dev or prod property of the params?

Example:

```
Parameters:
  env:
    Description: environment
    Type: String
    Default: dev

Mappings: 
  RegionMap: 
    dev: 
      HVM64: "ami-0ff8a91507f77f867"
      HVMG2: "ami-0a584ac55a7631c0c"
    prod: 
      HVM64: "ami-0bdb828fd58c52235"
      HVMG2: "ami-066ee5fd4a9ef77f1"
  DynamoTableName:
    dev: 'devtable'
    prod: 'prodtable'
  SomeOtherVar: ...

Resources: 
  myEC2Instance: 
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties: 
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - RegionMap
        - !Ref env
        - HVM64
      InstanceType: m1.small
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the Params https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Here is passing param with CLI. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html

Here is how to find value in Map.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html

Is this what you want?

Comment: I think so, can you look at my example and make sure im understanding this. In my example I just need to pass the env var from the cli and the right values will be grabbed from the maps?

Comment: yes looks good. Have you run into any errors in your testing?

Answer (score 0):

In case you or someone else need an example or a slightly different approach. I use separate config files for different environments, load them dynamically at runtime and populate parameter values.

If you are using command line, the following example should work to populate parameters at runtime.

```
aws --region ${region} cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ${stack_name} -- template-body file://${CFT_DIR}/${process}-stack.json --parameters ParameterKey=${param1},ParameterValue=${value1} ParameterKey=${param2},ParameterValue=${value2} ParameterKey=${param3},ParameterValue=${value3}
```

All the variables can be populated based on the config file loaded at runtime.

If you are using AWS java sdk, you can do the same thing with this example.

```
AmazonCloudFormation awsCFTClient = AmazonCloudFormationClientBuilder.defaultClient();

List<Parameter> listOfParameters = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
    listOfParameters.add(getParameter("param1", "value1"));
    listOfParameters.add(getParameter("param2", "value2"));

CreateStackRequest createStackRequest = new CreateStackRequest();
    createStackRequest.setStackName(stackName);
    createStackRequest.setTemplateURL(AWS_S3_URL + cftPath);
    createStackRequest.setParameters(listOfParameters);

awsCFTClient.createStack(createStackRequest);
```

Just populate the parameter values from config files and load config based on environment.